# Why not all files is commiting into bitbucket

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, javafx, bitbucket

I create new Project and create a new repository from bitbucket but after commiting my all file I see not all of them is commiting. I see some files are not commiting and there are is different color than commited files.
If you pay attention Main is different color it is exactly will commite but inside of controller packages not commiting they have a different color.
How I can include into commiting files, my controller package?
[image]

[image]

Before commiting there is no controller package how I can commite controller package also

Comment: If you are using Intellij-IDEA to commit, you should add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run from the clil `git status` If you have a list of files under "Untracked files" That means you didn't add the files to git so when you push them you will not see it in the repo.
All you need to do is `git add <file>...`

Answer (score 1):

According to the file status color, the files in the controllers package are Ignored, via internal Ignored Files list (Settings | Version Control | Ignored files

That is why they do not appear as unversioned in the IDE and it was not possible to add them into commit from UI.